# Pygame - Space Invaders Aliens

Tags: python, pygame

currently I have a row of aliens, and now I'm trying to make bullets shoot from a random alien  once the current bullets go off screen.

so far I have this for the bullets: http://pastebin.com/fR0gzkh6

which shoots a bullet from an alien at the starting point and continues to shoot from that x coord, but how can I make it take the current x coords of various different aliens and shoot from their current x coord.

this is the alien class: http://pastebin.com/kRpthdh4
and this is how i create a group of sprites for the aliens:

```
for i in range(5):
    self.alien_sprites.add(Alien((i*100)+10, 0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of the alien instances:

```
self.aliens = []
for i in range(5):
    alien = Alien((i*100)+10, 0)
    self.alien_sprites.add(alien)
    self.aliens.append(alien)
```

Now pick one at random to do something:

```
import random
random_alien = random.choice(self.aliens)
# Now do what you like
```

Comment: now with this, how can i retrieve the x coords and y coords of the alien that was randomly chosen?

Comment: You should probably store that in the Alien class. If you put your full code here instead of on a pastebin, that would help a lot.

Comment: I notice you're not actually using your bullet_list (or any list of bullets), so you'll only ever be able to properly render one bullet of each type. You can use a for-loop to update all bullets in a list: in a loop headered by `for bullet in bullet_list:`, `bullet` will take on the value of each bullet in the list in succession, so you can then update them all (or do anything else you want with them).

Comment: Python has a very rich random number library, including the `choice` method that selects a random member of a sequence: `random_alien = random.choice( self.aliens )`.

Comment: does anyone know how to get the current x coord and y coord of a random alien after i use ali's code?