# Pygame - Looping shooting bullets for space invaders

Tags: python, pygame

Right now my code has 2 random aliens shoot 1 bullet, but I want this to loop so that when the bullets leave the screen, it loops for 2 more random aliens shooting bullets and so on.

http://pastebin.com/RhXp2zss

the class for the alien bullets is called Alien_Bullets
within class Space_invaders there should be the sprite group for the alien bullets and I need to include the looping bullet effect within the function update under Space_invaders

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pygame - Space Invaders Aliens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660243/pygame-space-invaders-aliens)

Answer (score 1):

You should keep a reference to the Alien in your `Alien_Bullets`, then when de bullet gets destoyed you trigger a new shot. You can keep a counter in your Alien to know how many bullets it shot. When the counter reches 3 or the bullet hits the target you reset the counter and stop shooting.